Extracting returns closest to the date of purchase
I need an output like this I want to delete the return invoice closest to the date when a customer purchased the same product (same Itemcode, same ColorCode) after the date he purchased a product (ItemCode) for a customer. For example, if a single product is purchased and the same product is refunded, both rows (invoices) will be deleted. However, if 2 products are purchased in a single invoice and one of them is returned, only the refunded invoice will be removed from the table by deducting the refund amount and income (refund invoice) from the invoice containing these 2 product information.



CustomerCode
InvoiceNumber
IsReturn
InvoiceDate
ItemCode
ColorCode
Qty1
Revenue




15656858
193-R-7-373740
1
11.06.2022
4A1400000002
SYH
-1
-700


15656858
193-R-7-372193
0
27.05.2022
4A1400000002
SYH
2
1.400


15656858
193-R-7-373742
1
19.06.2023
4A1400000002
SYH
-1
-700


15656858
1-R-5-16844678
0
17.06.2023
4A1400000002
SYH
1
700


15656858
193-R-7-373781
1
12.06.2022
4A2022200036
YVZ
-1
-240


15656858
193-R-7-373502
0
10.06.2022
4A2022200036
YVZ
1
240


21069880
406-R-7-121023
0
4.05.2023
4A0121100002
YSL
1
200


21069880
406-R-7-120741
0
26.04.2023
4A1400000001
SYH
1
380


21069880
1-R-7-16894399
1
26.04.2023
4A1400000001
SYH
-1
-380


21069880
406-R-7-120740
0
26.04.2023
4A1400000001
SYH
1
880


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
0
3.09.2022
4A2000000013
amv
3
2.000


21069880
1-R-7-16894396
1
7.09.2022
4A2000000013
amv
-1
-667


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
0
3.09.2022
4A3022100145
GSY
1
1.587



So in the end I want to get an output like this:



CustomerCode
InvoiceNumber
IsReturn
InvoiceDate
ItemCode
ColorCode
Qty1
Revenue




15656858
193-R-7-372193
0
27.05.2022
4A1400000002
SYH
1
700


21069880
406-R-7-121023
0
4.05.2023
4A0121100002
YSL
1
200


21069880
406-R-7-120740
0
26.04.2023
4A1400000001
SYH
1
880


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
0
3.09.2022
4A3022100145
GSY
1
1.587


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
0
3.09.2022
4A2000000013
amv
2
1.333



I tried to use sum(Qty1)>0 but I found that it doesn't work in a larger example.

in the last question, there was a way to connect returns and invoices, but i don't see it here?

Unfortunately, I realized that for some invoices there is no link between returns and invoices, so I am stuck with the option to deduct the nearest return from the same customer following the invoice for the same product. If there is another way to deduct returns for such a situation, I would appreciate hearing your opinion.

 it doesn't work in a larger example Perhaps you should also include such scenario in your sample data

I want to determine the rows that I deleted as a return. For this reason, it made sense to organize according to the return date closest to the invoice. This is not possible when I write “sum(Qty1)>0” because there is nothing connecting invoices and returns (I may be thinking wrong).

This is complicated to achieve in one query (at least for me). You can do a loop where you process return in row_number() order and match it to closest invoice by date and store the connection in a #t-table. In every iteration, you check so invoice isn't already fully covered

Top 1 < date union all top 1> date.. Then calc date diff in code for the one you want. (TLDR - if < date that is the solution alone)

If we only had to deal with quantities, we could use a recursive CTE to step through the transactions while tracking and allocating returns. (See this db<>fiddle.) However, since the revenue-per-item is not constant for a given part (4A1400000001/SYH - 380 vs 880), we would need to track and allocate both return quantity and multiple revenue values, which would require maintaining a multi-valued stack. This exceeds my ability to code this as a CTE.

The alternative is to add another table to your database that explicitly links return invoices to their corresponding purchase invoices. Something like CREATE TABLE Returns ( OriginalInvoiceNumber VARCHAR(20), ReturnInvoiceNumber VARCHAR(20), Qty INT, Revenue NUMERIC(10,0) ). This would be populated using a look that matches up returns with prior purchases, that have not already been offset by other returns. Note that a return might involve multiple purchases and vice versa. Once populated, your final query could join and make the necessary adjustments based on this table.

Because the allocation of returns is potentially dependent on the allocation of any prior returns for the same customer/product/color combination, and those allocations are also very sensitive to the ordering of the purchases and returns mix, this cannot be done without some form of looping logic or recursive CTE that processes and allocates returns in ascending date order.
We also need to consider various return scenarios. While the most common scenarios may be a single purchase followed by a single return or partial return, we should also consider the following possibilities, even if unlikely.

A single purchase followed my multiple partial returns.
Multiple purchases followed by a single full or partial return.
A purchase/purchase/return/return, where the first return is matched to the second (later) purchase and the second return is matched to the remaining earlier purchase.
A combination of purchases and returns followed later by a completely independent combination of purchases.
A complex combination of purchases and returns where there is no one-to-one relationship, where some returns span multiple purchases and some purchases are involved in multiple returns.

The goal would be a general solution that naturally covers all of the above scenarios.
If we only had to deal with quantities, we could use a recursive CTE to step through the transactions while tracking and allocating returns, working in reverse date order. (See this db<>fiddle.) However, the unit-cost (revenue/quantity) is not constant for a given part in your data (example 4A1400000001/SYH - has unit costs 380 and 880), so the allocations become much more complicated. A CTE solution would need to build a stack of some sort - possibly a comma-separated list, XML or JSON representation that is unpacked, modified, and repacked at each step of the recursive CTE. This would be computationally expensive and I believe would exceed the capabilities of a CTE.
So the fallback is to define a ReturnAllocation table and use a cursor and while loop to populate that table with the allocations for each return, taking into account potential earlier returns at each step. From there your final query can pull the Invoice data, and adjust the quantity and revenue values in each row by any amounts (if any) present in matching rows the ReturnAllocation table. Any rows whose adjusted amounts are zero would then be excluded.
I was initially thinking of a table defined like ReturnAllocation(PurchaseInvoiceNumber, ReturnInvoiceNumber, AllocatedQty, AllocatedRevenue), but discovered that InvoiceNumber is not unique in your data. This necessitated adding ItemCode and ColorCode to the design.
CREATE TABLE ReturnAllocation (
    PurchaseInvoiceNumber VARCHAR(20),
    ReturnInvoiceNumber VARCHAR(20),
    ItemCode VARCHAR(20),
    ColorCode VARCHAR(20),
    AllocatedQty INT,
    AllocatedRevenue NUMERIC(10,0)
)

CREATE INDEX IX_ReturnAllocation_PurchaseInvoiceNumber
    ON ReturnAllocation(PurchaseInvoiceNumber, ItemCode, ColorCode)
    INCLUDE(AllocatedQty, AllocatedRevenue)

CREATE INDEX IX_ReturnAllocation_ReturnInvoiceNumber
    ON ReturnAllocation(ReturnInvoiceNumber, ItemCode, ColorCode)
    INCLUDE(AllocatedQty, AllocatedRevenue)

The indexes above support efficient lookups.
Next, the following logic can be used to calculate the allocations and populate the table. This will process returns in date-ascending order and will attempt to match the returns up with the most recent prior purchases, not already returned. If different purchases have different unit-prices, the PriceDifference logic will prefer purchases having the same unit-price values.
DECLARE
    @CustomerCode INT,
    @InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(20),
    @IsReturn BIT,
    @InvoiceDate DATE,
    @ItemCode VARCHAR(20),
    @ColorCode VARCHAR(20),
    @Qty1 INT,
    @Revenue NUMERIC(10,0)

DECLARE ReturnCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM Invoice
    WHERE IsReturn = 1
    ORDER BY InvoiceDate -- Process returns in order
OPEN ReturnCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM ReturnCursor INTO 
    @CustomerCode, @InvoiceNumber, @IsReturn, @InvoiceDate,
    @ItemCode, @ColorCode, @Qty1, @Revenue
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- Identify the most recent preceding not-yet-returned purchases and insert
    -- one or more return allocation rows starting at the latest matching purchase
    -- and working our wayt back until the entire return is allocated.
    INSERT ReturnAllocation
    SELECT
        P.InvoiceNumber,  -- PurchaseInvoiceNumber,
        @InvoiceNumber,   -- ReturnInvoiceNumber,
        @ItemCode,
        @ColorCode,
        AQ.AllocatedQty,
        ROUND(@Revenue * 1e0 / @Qty1 * AQ.AllocatedQty, 0) AS AllocatedRevenue
    FROM (
        -- Find prior matching purchases (adjusted for prior returns)
        SELECT
            I.*,
            UQ.UnreturnedQty,
            ISNULL(SUM(UQ.UnreturnedQty)
                    OVER(
                        ORDER BY PD.PriceDifference, I.InvoiceDate DESC, I.InvoiceNumber DESC
                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                    )
                , 0) AS MoreRecentUnreturnedQtys
        FROM Invoice I
        CROSS APPLY (
            -- Idenify and count any prior return allocations for this purchase 
            SELECT ISNULL(SUM(RA.AllocatedQty), 0) AS ReturnedQty
            FROM ReturnAllocation RA
            WHERE RA.PurchaseInvoiceNumber = I.InvoiceNumber
            AND RA.ItemCode = I.ItemCode
            AND RA.ColorCode = I.ColorCode
        ) RQ
        CROSS APPLY (
            -- Available unreturned quantity is the original purchase quantity
            -- minus any amount already returned
            SELECT I.Qty1 - RQ.ReturnedQty AS UnreturnedQty
        ) UQ
        CROSS APPLY (
            -- Since price may vary, prefer purchases having a matching price
            SELECT ROUND(ABS(
                    @Revenue * 1e0 / @Qty1 - I.Revenue * 1e0 / I.Qty1
                ), 0) AS PriceDifference
        ) PD
        WHERE I.CustomerCode = @CustomerCode
        AND I.ItemCode = @ItemCode
        AND I.ColorCode = @ColorCode
        AND I.InvoiceDate <= @InvoiceDate
        AND I.IsReturn = 0 -- Look only at purchases
    ) P
    CROSS APPLY (
        -- Figure out how much to allocate to this purchase. This will be the total
        -- return amount minus what might have already been allocated to later
        -- purchaces, but no more than the available (not-yet-returned) quantity for
        -- the current purchase.
        SELECT LEAST(P.UnreturnedQty, -@Qty1 - P.MoreRecentUnreturnedQtys) AS AllocatedQty
    ) AQ
    WHERE AQ.AllocatedQty > 0

    FETCH NEXT FROM ReturnCursor INTO 
        @CustomerCode, @InvoiceNumber, @IsReturn, @InvoiceDate,
        @ItemCode, @ColorCode, @Qty1, @Revenue
END -- While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

CLOSE ReturnCursor
DEALLOCATE ReturnCursor

One key point in the above logic is the is the ORDER BY in the SUM(...) OVER(...) window function. This, together with the I.InvoiceDate <= @InvoiceDate, controls what order the purchases are considered when picking the top candidates to be matched with the current return.
Sample computed allocation data:



PurchaseInvoiceNumber
ReturnInvoiceNumber
ItemCode
ColorCode
AllocatedQty
AllocatedRevenue




193-R-7-372193
193-R-7-373740
4A1400000002
SYH
1
700


193-R-7-373502
193-R-7-373781
4A2022200036
YVZ
1
240


1-R-7-16853468
1-R-7-16894396
4A2000000013
amv
1
667


406-R-7-120741
1-R-7-16894399
4A1400000001
SYH
1
380


1-R-5-16844678
193-R-7-373742
4A1400000002
SYH
1
700



It would be better if returns were matched up with purchases at the time they are added to the database. Perhaps you already have this data, since most point-of-sale systems will require that the original purchase be identified by scanning the receipt or looking up prior purchases at the time of the return.
Finally, the following query will retrieve the Invoice data, adjust the quantity and revenue values based on matching ReturnAllocation data, and filter out and rows where both quantities go to zero.
SELECT I.*, ADJ.AdjustedQty, ADJ.AdjusteddRevenue
FROM Invoice I
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        ISNULL(SUM(AllocatedQty), 0) AS SumAllocatedQty,
        ISNULL(SUM(AllocatedRevenue), 0) AS SumAllocatedRevenue
    FROM ReturnAllocation RA
    WHERE RA.PurchaseInvoiceNumber = I.InvoiceNumber
    AND RA.ItemCode = I.ItemCode
    AND RA.ColorCode = I.ColorCode
) R1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        ISNULL(SUM(AllocatedQty), 0) AS SumAllocatedQty,
        ISNULL(SUM(AllocatedRevenue), 0) AS SumAllocatedRevenue
    FROM ReturnAllocation RA
    WHERE RA.ReturnInvoiceNumber = I.InvoiceNumber
    AND RA.ItemCode = I.ItemCode
    AND RA.ColorCode = I.ColorCode
) R2
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        I.Qty1 - R1.SumAllocatedQty + R2.SumAllocatedQty AS AdjustedQty,
        I.Revenue - R1.SumAllocatedRevenue + R2.SumAllocatedRevenue AS AdjusteddRevenue
) ADJ
WHERE NOT (ADJ.AdjustedQty = 0 AND ADJ.AdjusteddRevenue = 0)
ORDER BY
    I.CustomerCode, I.ItemCode, I.ColorCode,
    I.InvoiceDate, I.IsReturn, I.InvoiceNumber

Sample results:



CustomerCode
InvoiceNumber
IsReturn
InvoiceDate
ItemCode
ColorCode
Qty1
Revenue
AdjustedQty
AdjusteddRevenue




15656858
193-R-7-372193
False
2022-05-27
4A1400000002
SYH
2
1400
1
700


21069880
406-R-7-121023
False
2023-05-04
4A0121100002
YSL
1
200
1
200


21069880
406-R-7-120740
False
2023-04-26
4A1400000001
SYH
1
880
1
880


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
False
2022-09-03
4A2000000013
amv
3
2000
2
1333


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
False
2022-09-03
4A3022100145
GSY
1
1587
1
1587



The above includes both the original and adjusted amounts for comparison. You can of course tailor the final select list to your needs.
CROSS APPLYs have been used multiple times in the above code as a convenient way yo encapsulate intermediate calculations for readability, to avoid duplication of calculations, and to reduce clutter in the final select lists. This technique is a matter of style preference and you can eliminate many of these CROSS APPLYs by substituting the contained expressions where the resulting values are used.
Note that if any the returns cannot be (fully) allocated based on the defined matching rules, they will remain as unmatched returns in the results.  Also, roundoff errors could potentially leave residual amounts if the unit-price is not a whole number. These could be eliminated by tweaking or eliminating the ADJ.AdjusteddRevenue = 0 condition in the query.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo with some extra test data.

First of all, thank you very much for your wonderful and detailed solution. ” ‘LEAST’ is not a recognized built-in function name. "How can I solve this problem?

LEAST() is a function in SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions you can replace it with a CASE expression of IIF() function - CASE WHEN P.UnreturnedQty < -@Qty1 - P.MoreRecentUnreturnedQtys THEN P.UnreturnedQty ELSE -@Qty1 - P.MoreRecentUnreturnedQtys END or IIF(P.UnreturnedQty < -@Qty1 - P.MoreRecentUnreturnedQtys, P.UnreturnedQty, -@Qty1 - P.MoreRecentUnreturnedQtys).  Fiddle.

Thanks a lot, really great solution and it worked on the small sample data set, but the data set in the database contains over 2 million data and the query takes too long on this data set. It is not completed even after hours :(

If not already present, adding an index on Invoice(CustomerCode, ItemCode, ColorCode) or at a minimum Invoice(CustomerCode) would significantly speed up candidate purchase selection. Beyond that, you may just need to bear the cost of initially populating a persistent ReturnAllocation table. You might consider populating data in batches or perhaps one day or month at a time. After that, you need only worry about keeping that table up-to-date as new returns are recorded.  The final query should be reasonably fast, as long as you are trying to select the entire sales history in one query.

Calculating the allocations on the fly, running your query, and discarding the calculated allocation data after each use would be very expensive and is not recommended. If you cannot add a persistent ReturnAllocation table, the only other thing I can think of is to ensure that the return allocation logic only processes returns included in the date range or customer set that will be included in the final query. I cannot think of any design that can efficiently handle this much data on-the-fly without a persistent ReturnAllocation table.

Maybe it is not all the way there but maybe you can get any ideas from this:
with data (CustomerCode,    InvoiceNumber,  IsReturn,   InvoiceDate,    ItemCode,   ColorCode,  Qty1,   Revenue)as ( 
select 15656858,    '193-R-7-373740',   1,  '11.06.2022',   '4A1400000002', 'SYH',  -1, -700 union all
select 15656858,    '193-R-7-372193',   0,  '27.05.2022',   '4A1400000002', 'SYH',  2,  1400 union all
select 15656858,    '193-R-7-373742',   1,  '19.06.2023',   '4A1400000002', 'SYH',  -1, -700 union all
select 15656858,    '1-R-5-16844678',   0,  '17.06.2023',   '4A1400000002', 'SYH',  1,  700 union all
select 15656858,    '193-R-7-373781',   1,  '12.06.2022',   '4A2022200036', 'YVZ',  -1, -240 union all
select 15656858,    '193-R-7-373502',   0,  '10.06.2022',   '4A2022200036', 'YVZ',  1,  240 union all
select 21069880,    '406-R-7-121023',   0,  '4.05.2023',    '4A0121100002', 'YSL',  1,  200 union all
select 21069880,    '406-R-7-120741',   0,  '26.04.2023',   '4A1400000001', 'SYH',  1,  380 union all
select 21069880,    '1-R-7-16894399',   1,  '26.04.2023',   '4A1400000001', 'SYH',  -1, -380 union all
select 21069880,    '406-R-7-120740',   0,  '26.04.2023',   '4A1400000001', 'SYH',  1,  880 union all
select 21069880,    '1-R-7-16853468',   0,  '3.09.2022',    '4A2000000013', 'amv',  3,  2000 union all
select 21069880,    '1-R-7-16894396',   1,  '7.09.2022',    '4A2000000013', 'amv',  -1, -667 union all
select 21069880,    '1-R-7-16853468',   0,  '3.09.2022',    '4A3022100145', 'GSY',  1,  1587
),
dataReturn as (
select CustomerCode,        IsReturn,       ItemCode,   ColorCode,  sum(Qty1) as Qty1,  sum(Revenue ) as Revenue
from data where isReturn = 1
group by CustomerCode,      IsReturn,       ItemCode,   ColorCode
),
dataSale as (
select CustomerCode,    max(InvoiceNumber) as InvoiceNumber,    IsReturn,   max(InvoiceDate)InvoiceDate,    ItemCode,   ColorCode,  sum(Qty1) as Qty1,  sum(Revenue ) as Revenue
from data where isReturn = 0
group by CustomerCode,  IsReturn,   ItemCode,   ColorCode
)

select s.CustomerCode,  s.InvoiceNumber,    s.IsReturn, s.InvoiceDate,  s.ItemCode, s.ColorCode,     Qty1,   Revenue 
from dataSale s
 where not exists 
 (select 1 from dataReturn r where s.CustomerCode = r.CustomerCode and s.ItemCode = r.ItemCode and s.ColorCode = r.ColorCode)

union all
select s.CustomerCode,  s.InvoiceNumber,    s.IsReturn, s.InvoiceDate,  s.ItemCode, s.ColorCode,    s.Qty1+r.Qty1 as Qty1,  (s.Revenue + r.Revenue) as Revenue 
from dataSale s
join dataReturn r on s.CustomerCode = r.CustomerCode
and s.ItemCode = r.ItemCode
and s.ColorCode = r.ColorCode


Here's a self-contained, non-cursor query that doesn't require an auxiliary table. It computes each transactions starting "height" based on incrementing or decrementing a running total according to purchase versus return. (My logic uses the quantity rather than the bit values to differentiate but that is easily changed.)
To get the number of returns against a purchase, in theory each level value needs to be searched to see if a return exists in the future where the level has crosses that baseline again. The first time that happens is the return that effectively cancels out an individual unit purchase. And because of that, the way quick to accomplish this calculation is to just scan forward seeking the minimum height of subsequent returns. That value then makes it trivial to determine how big an adjustment must be made to the quantity.
with data as (
    select *,
        round(Revenue / Qty1, 0) as UnitRevenue,
        dense_rank() over (order by CustomerCode, ItemCode, ColorCode, round(Revenue / Qty1, 0)) as dr,
        row_number() over (partition by CustomerCode, ItemCode, ColorCode, round(Revenue / Qty1, 0)
                           order by InvoiceDate, -Qty1) as rn,
        sum(Qty1) over (partition by CustomerCode, ItemCode, ColorCode, round(Revenue / Qty1, 0)
                           order by InvoiceDate, -Qty1)
          + case when Qty1 > 0 then - Qty1 + sign(Qty1) else 1 end as height
    from Invoice
)
select
    p.CustomerCode, p.InvoiceNumber,
    cast(0 as bit) as IsReturn, p.InvoiceDate, p.ItemCode, p.ColorCode,
    p.Qty1 - m.adjustment as Qty1,
    p.Revenue - m.adjustment * p.UnitRevenue as Revenue
from data p cross apply (
    select case when min(r.height) <= p.height then p.Qty1
                else coalesce(p.height + p.Qty1 - min(r.height), 0) end as adjustment
    from data r 
    where r.dr = p.dr and r.rn > p.rn and r.Qty1 < 0
) m
where p.Qty1 > 0 /* redundant but likely to improve query plan */
    and p.Qty1 > m.adjustment
order by CustomerCode, ItemCode;

https://dbfiddle.uk/Qp6cPDzA
I do assume that all returns are properly pair with an actual purchase (by date order.) Also I'm matching strictly on the same unit revenue values. Finally, I computed a dr number to serve as a key value for buckets of rows with common customer/item/color/unit cost. If you needed to incorporate a bit of wiggle room for the revenue amounts that might be one way to do it.
In the attached fiddle there's a second query that shows how the details of the contributing purchase and return invoices pairs could be listed out in case that's useful.

Hello. Thank you very much for your help. It was a really effective solution. But I have the same problem as above. In the sample data set, I can get the result I want immediately, but in data over 2 million, the query has been running for 3 hours. Is there any way to overcome this :(

It would probably be helpful to report the indexing on the table and to look at the query plan. This tweak might give a boost though: where r.CustomerCode = p.CustomerCode and r.InvoiceDate >= p.InvoiceDate and r.dr = p.dr and r.rn > p.rn and r.Qty1 < 0
